# How to remove cookies using CookieManager for a specific domain?

Tags: android, cookies, webkit

I know about the existince of [CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html), but how do I remove cookies of a domain only?

Can someone help me with some code fragment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call `android.webkit.CookieManager`'s `getCookie` method to generate a RFC 2109 `Cookie` header for the URL or domain you are interested. Parse the cookie header to get a list of cookie names. For each cookie name, generate a RFC 2109 `Set-Cookie` header for that name that has an expiry date in the past and pass it into `CookieManager`'s `setCookie` method. Although the API docs specify that `setCookie` ignores values that have expired, Android's current implementation actually flushes the cookie in this case. To guard against future implementations that do ignore expired values as specified in the documentation, check that the cookies were actually removed and perform some fallback behaviour if they haven't—`CookieManager`'s `removeAllCookie` method may be useful for this fallback.

Comment: Is there any cookie parser in android that can help us with this? Or should we be just doing split() and all ourselves?

Comment: @Enigma read the RFC, it describes the exact format the cookie string will be in.

Comment: yeah, if you could post some code, that would be great!

Comment: @Enigma To parse cookie headers use: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpCookie.html

Comment: did anyone get this to work?  I tried going this route, but the cookie never get set with the expires tag.  Also when you call removeExpirecookies, the cookie remains the same.

Comment: @darewreck Faced the same issue. The cookie never gets set with expiry tag. While reading it back it always comes up and also on the string red the expiry tag is always missing.

Comment: @darewreck Cold you please help me on the same problem.. I want to just remove the specific cookie from the cookiemanager but above approach not working while i am setting the date of the past time..Could you please give the suggestion on it...Thanks

Answer (score 12):

```
public void clearCookies(String domain) {
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    String cookiestring = cookieManager.getCookie(domain);
    String[] cookies =  cookiestring.split(";");
    for (int i=0; i<cookies.length; i++) {
        String[] cookieparts = cookies[i].split("=");
        cookieManager.setCookie(domain, cookieparts[0].trim()+"=; Expires=Wed, 31 Dec 2025 23:59:59 GMT");
    }
}
```

Comment: "Expires" part of your answer saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: From what research I've done, it seems you need to provide the domain and path when calling setCookie(). Passing in the domain alone doesn't work for me, and I can't find a way to obtain the paths of the cookies for a given domain -- just the names and values.

Comment: In the sample code, why is the expires date in the future?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could make the date in the past too.

Comment: Thanks @TomKincaid, your suggestion saved my day too. Btw, we no longer need CookieSyncManager as the webview will perform sync itself. And it's already deprecated in API Level 21. Read more here...https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager

Comment: @TommyLeong Cold you please help me on the same problem.. I want to just remove the specific cookie from the cookiemanager but above approach not working while i am setting the date of the past time..Could you please give the suggestion on it...Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code sample from an open source project. Maybe could help someone.

https://github.com/janrain/engage.android/blob/96f21b45738ef82a911e27d8a707aff3a1024d36/Jump/src/com/janrain/android/utils/WebViewUtils.java

```
private static void deleteWebViewCookiesForDomain(Context context, String domain, boolean secure) {
    CookieSyncManager csm = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
    CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();

    /* http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19294 */
    if (AndroidUtils.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        // don't trim leading '.'s
    } else {
        /* Trim leading '.'s */
        if (domain.startsWith(".")) domain = domain.substring(1);
    }

    /* Cookies are stored by domain, and are not different for different schemes (i.e. http vs
     * https) (although they do have an optional 'secure' flag.) */
    domain = "http" + (secure ? "s" : "") + "://" + domain;
    String cookieGlob = cm.getCookie(domain);
    if (cookieGlob != null) {
        String[] cookies = cookieGlob.split(";");
        for (String cookieTuple : cookies) {
            String[] cookieParts = cookieTuple.split("=");

            /* setCookie has changed a lot between different versions of Android with respect to
             * how it handles cookies like these, which are set in order to clear an existing
             * cookie.  This way of invoking it seems to work on all versions. */
            cm.setCookie(domain, cookieParts[0] + "=;");

            /* These calls have worked for some subset of the the set of all versions of
             * Android:
             * cm.setCookie(domain, cookieParts[0] + "=");
             * cm.setCookie(domain, cookieParts[0]); */
        }
        csm.sync();
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I just need to make sure the domain name is correct (start with a "."), it will reset all the cookie values to empty string. Works well.

Comment: I think there something wrong with this function. After I executed it for "twitter.com" and "api.twitter.com" Twitter doesn't load anymore (empty page on Android emulator 6.0). However, it works for Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anyway to do this in the API, but you can always dig into the real source code (open source is nice)... for example, I found this `deleteCookies` method in this class: [WebViewDatabase](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=es#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewDatabase.java&q=android%20deleteCookies&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc&l=455) which is part of the core of Android.

As you can see there... cookies are just rows into a SQLite Database... so if you can make this class work, at least you know how to do it by your self.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but I'm looking into this myself.  Is there a possibility for conflicts if I modify the webview.db database myself?  Are there thread safety and locking issues if the CookieSyncManager or a WebView accesses it while I am modifying it?